# Java - Conditional show null value xml tag

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like this

```
public class Book {
  private String contributor;
  private String nocontributor;
  private String edition;
  private String noedition;
}
```

Now get book's info from database, if the book has contributor called John Doe and edition is First Edition. Then this object could be converted to xml like:

```
<Contributor>John Doe</Contributor>
<Edition>First Edition</Edition>
```

Or if the book **doesn't** have contributor and edition info, the return xml should like:

```
<NoContributor/>
<NoEdition/>
```

I tried using annotation like:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

The return xml would omit all fields.

If I don't use the annotation, the return xml would like:

```
<Contributor/>
<NoContributor/>
<Edition/>
<NoEdition/>
```

Please suggest possible solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: You could use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation only for fields you want to ignore and for `contributor` and `edition` do not use at all.

Comment: Just saw this library mentioned in another answer: https://github.com/monitorjbl/json-view That could be a solution for you.